# roslaunch error IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run

```
roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:="rospack find robot1_description/urdf/robot1.urdf"
```

and get some errors below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 306, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 749, in load self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 721, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 665, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 265, in _param_tag
    value = self.param_value(verbose, name, ptype, *vals)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/loader.py", line 472, in param_value
    with open(textfile, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'rospack find robot1_description/urdf/robot1.urdf'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324149/roslaunch-error-ioerror:-%5Berrno-2%5D-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Yangyh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41873/yangyh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:="rospack find robot1_description/urdf/robot1.urdf"
> ```

You need to use backticks, not regular quotes. This is `bash`, not `roslaunch`.

The correct command would be:

```
roslaunch robot1_description display.launch model:="`rospack find robot1_description`/urdf/robot1.urdf"
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yangyh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41873/yangyh/) on 2019-05-28**:
thank you for all the help me to sovle my problem. thank you! Can I contact you later?